# SQLite query to delete matched part of a string + all text that follows

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with rows where I would like to replace the content in a column as follows:

```
text1.... word1...text2
```

I only know the `word1`, and I would like to delete `word1` and the rest of the string, `text2` in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about the problem as *keeping everything up to `word1`* you can see that it can be solved with `substr` and `instr`, something along the lines of

```
UPDATE table SET column = substr(column, 1, instr(column, 'word1')-1);
```

Note that `substr()` and `instr()` are SQLite specific, other engines may have similar functions with different names.